# How do I set a javascript variable to the return of an inline function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm using the code:

```
var x = function() {return true;};
```

trying to set x to true, the return value of the function, but instead x is defined as the function itself. How can I set x as the return value of the function? I could easily code around this problem by using a non-inline function or some such, but it bugs me because I'm sure there must be a simple solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The solution is to define the function and then invoke it (by adding the extra parentheses at the end):

```
    var x = ( function() {return true;} ) ();
```

Answer (score 9):

You're not executing the function, you're setting `x` to actually be the function.

If you had some variable `y`, it could take on the value of the function with something like:

```
var x = function(){ return true; };
var y = x();  // y is now set to true.
```

or alternatively execute the function in place with:

```
var x = (function(){ return true; })();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code just defines the function and assigns it to `x`, the function doesn't get called. To call it, put the function in parenthesis and add `()` after it, like for a normal function call:

```
    var x = 
        (
            function () { 
                return true;
            } 
        )();
```